# Using @media style in HTML head

Tags: html

I am new to html and am just creating a test webpage for curiosity sake. I am trying to make it so that when my browser window is less than 800 pixels wide my divs occupy the whole width of the screen. Otherwise they should occupy 45% of it and be inline blocks. I used the code below. They are all 45% width inline blocks regardless of my window size. Am I just using the @media tag incorrectly? I would like to define the styles in the head of the html code if possible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title> Page</title>
        <style type="text/css"> @media screen and (max-width: 800px) { div { 
width: 100%}} div {display: inline-block; width: 45%; height: 50px; 
background-color: purple} </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Order/Position matters (top to down)

The problem in your code, you check the screen, if less than 800px you set to 100%, then you overwrite the width to 45% anyway, it will always be 45%.

think about you set the width to 45% first, then if the screen size less than 800px, overwrite it to 100% (NOTE: all other CSS rules are still the same unless you overwrite inside that `@media div`)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>
    <title> Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      div {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 45%;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: purple
      }
      
      @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
        div {
          width: 100%
        }
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>a</div>
    <div>a</div>
    <div>a</div>
    <div>a</div>
    <div>a</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ah hooray it works thank you. Okay next question, why when I inspect the page and use chrome's device simulator does it not work, but when I manually shrink the size of my browser window it works?

Comment: @AronDuncanstein Nice, If the answer is what you looking for mark it as [Correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for the future readers. Thank you!